# Multi-conditional join

Tags: mysql

I bet this is an easy question but my MySQL chops are a bit rusty. Need a little help generating a proper query for the following scenario with a multi conditional join. I have one table to attributes (think tags) and another table which have a list of records. Running into problems when I want to match a page which has more then one attribute defined in the query.

```
+--------------------------------------+
| ATTRIBUTES                           |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| name      | value      | page_id     |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| type        food         2           |  
| fruit       apple        2           |  
| color       green        2           |
| type        frog         3           |  
| color       green        3           |
+--------------------------------------+


+--------------------------------------+
| PAGES                                |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| page_id      | title                 |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| 2              Granny Smith          |  
| 3              Kermit the Frog       |
+--------------------------------------+
```

USE CASES

```
Query: type+food
Results: Granny Smith

Query: color+green
Results: Granny Smith, Kermit the Frog

Query: type+food and color+green
Results: Granny Smith
```

This is the query I was playing with, but obviously not working:

```
SELECT page.page_id, page.title 
FROM page_attributes 
LEFT JOIN page ON (page_attributes.page_id = page.page_id) 
WHERE (page_attributes.name = 'color' 
AND page_attributes.value = 'green') 
AND (page_attributes.name = 'type' 
AND page_attributes.value = 'food')
```

Comment: Show us the SQL you've tried, please.

Comment: What query do you have that is not working?

Comment: if you only want the results you state, then you don't need a join at all...

Comment: Added my (crappy) query and updated use case examples to need join table.

Comment: How are the results you're getting different from what you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the same lines as Nitro has, but keep the criteria for the attributes WITH the ON clause.  Also, make sure you have an index on your attributes table on ( page_id, name, value ) so the joins will be optimized.

```
SELECT 
      page.page_id, 
      page.title 
   FROM 
      page

         INNER JOIN page_attributes a1 
           ON page.page_id = a1.page_id
           AND a1.name = 'color'
           AND a1.value = 'green'

         INNER JOIN page_attributes a2
           ON page.page_id = a2.page_id
           AND a2.name = 'type'
           AND a2.value = 'food'

   LIMIT 10
```

As you can see, you want to add another "criteria", just copy/past the entire join.  It either finds a match and allows to include, or it doesn't and ignores the page record.

Comment: Works perfect and easy to automate. Thanks.

Comment: @LouisW, I suspected you would be looking into an automation, and yes, this is easier then multiple joins and adjusting the WHERE clause.  However, both solutions are good options.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this, even if there might be a more efficient way, is to craft a query with multiple `INNER JOIN`s, one for each attribute. With an `INNER JOIN`, as opposed to a `LEFT JOIN` all the condition must be true for the main row to match.

```
SELECT page.page_id, page.title 
  FROM page
INNER JOIN page_attributes a1 ON (a1.page_id = page.page_id)
INNER JOIN page_attributes a2 ON (a2.page_id = page.page_id)
 WHERE (a1.name = 'color' AND a1.value = 'green') 
   AND (a2.name = 'type'  AND a2.value = 'food')
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to apply all conditions simultaneously to different rows of the join.  Here's what the joined relation (before any `SELECT` or `WHERE` filtering) might look like:

```
Joined relation:
+--------------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+
| page_id      | title                 | name        | value       |
+--------------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2              Granny Smith            type          food        |
| 2              Granny Smith            color         green       |
| 2              Granny Smith            fruit         apple       |
| 3              Kermit the Frog         color         green       |
| 3              Kermit the Frog         type          frog        |
+--------------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The WHERE clause will apply to each row of this intermediate result.  So, the clause in your query:

```
WHERE (page_attributes.name = 'color' 
AND page_attributes.value = 'green') 
AND (page_attributes.name = 'type' 
AND page_attributes.value = 'food')
```

will be false for each row of that joined relation.

Simply changing the `AND`s to `OR`s won't work, because that will simply find pages with ANY of the tag values, not ALL of them, which is what you really want the query to do.

Unfortunately, with this table structure, there's no general, standardized way to do this for an arbitrary number of tags being queried.  The suggestions in other answers to use multiple joins to the `page_attributes` table will work if you know in advance how many tags will be queried on, and you can achieve a similar effect with multiple `UNION`ed queries.  But again, those will only work if you fix the number of tags to query.

The least complex general solution is to avoid trying to do it all in SQL.  Perform the join and any `WHERE` conditions not dependent on the tag values, and then let the application code iterate over the results and enforce the tag query logic.